# Configuring 2008 reporting service in sql server 2005 instance

Tags: sql

can we configure 2008 reporting service in sql server 2005 instance? will there be any compatibility issues if you do so?

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you that from my last conversations with MS Support, it's not a officially supported configuration by Microsoft.  That having been said, I have done this a number of times and it has worked flawlessly each time -- I've used SSRS 2008 R2 against SQL 2005 very successfully.

That's not to say that it will continue to work when MS releases an SSRS service pack down the line, but I would frankly have a hard time believing that MS would release a SSRS service pack which would break this configuration.

I would say do it, but you should have a plan to migrate your SQL 2005 Database Engine instances to SQL 2008 R2 or the next upcoming version soon, as SQL 2005 mainstream support ended on April 12, 2011.